# Empty Csv generated by grails function

Tags: java, grails, apache-commons

I'm trying to generate a csv file using apache commons csv in grails project.
That's the code:

```
def createAndDownloadExcelTuttiCampiRichiesta( ArrayList result ) {
        def response = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().getCurrentResponse()
        response.setContentType('application/CSV')
        response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'Attachment;Filename="report.csv"')
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(response.outputStream)
            CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader("ID","Name","Designation","Company"))
            csvPrinter.printRecord("1", "Test", "Test", "Test")
            csvPrinter.printRecord("2", "Test", "Test", "Test")
            csvPrinter.printRecord("3", "Test", "Test", "Test")
            csvPrinter.printRecord("4", "Test", "Test", "Test")
            csvPrinter.flush()
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("Error parsing csv")
        }
        return
}
```

But it generate an empty csv file.
Why?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The details may change a bit depending on which version of Grails you like, but the code in https://github.com/jeffbrown/francodecsv/tree/master/grails-app works.  Startup the app and send a request to http://localhost:8080/demo and that should download a CSV that looks like this...

```
$ cat ~/Downloads/report.csv
ID,Name,Designation,Company
1,Test,Test,Test
2,Test,Test,Test
3,Test,Test,Test
4,Test,Test,Test
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/francodecsv/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/francodecsv/DemoController.groovy

```
package francodecsv

class DemoController {

    DemoService demoService

    def index() {
        demoService.createAndDownloadExcelTuttiCampiRichiesta([])
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/francodecsv/blob/master/grails-app/services/francodecsv/DemoService.groovy

```
package francodecsv

import grails.web.api.ServletAttributes
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter

class DemoService implements ServletAttributes {

    // result is ignored in this particular example... unclear from
    // the StackOverflow question what that is supposed to be used for
    void createAndDownloadExcelTuttiCampiRichiesta(ArrayList result) {
        response.setContentType('application/CSV')
        response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'Attachment;Filename="report.csv"')
        CharArrayWriter writer = new CharArrayWriter()
        CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader("ID", "Name", "Designation", "Company"))
        csvPrinter.printRecord("1", "Test", "Test", "Test")
        csvPrinter.printRecord("2", "Test", "Test", "Test")
        csvPrinter.printRecord("3", "Test", "Test", "Test")
        csvPrinter.printRecord("4", "Test", "Test", "Test")
        csvPrinter.flush()
        response.outputStream << writer.toCharArray()
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing some other factors in your app but the way you have the code written right now, I think you might be getting an `IllegalStateException` and not realizing it because of your log levels.  I expect you are getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response` but can't say for sure.